# Logging data from a subprocess (python,linux)

Tags: python, linux, subprocess

I'm running two scripts in parallel as follows:

```
import subprocess
from time import sleep
subprocess.Popen(["python3", 'tsn.py'])
subprocess.Popen(["python3", 'lsn.py'])
```

The above code is in a file called multi.py

Both 'tsn.py' and 'lsn.py' were logging data to separate text files using file.write(). If I run the .py files individually they log data just fine, however when I run multi.py the data to be logged prints on my screen just fine, but it doesn't get logged in the text files (i.e file.write() doesn't execute ).
What is the issue and how do I work around that? Thanks.

EDIT:
lsn.py looks like this. tsn.py is almost exactly the same

```
from socket import *
import time

serverName_sen = '192.168.0.151'
serverPort_sen = 8080
clientSocket_sen = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)
clientSocket_sen.connect((serverName_sen,serverPort_sen))
get='getd'
status='off'
logvar = 0
file = open('lsn_log.txt', 'a')

while 1:
    time.sleep(0.5)
    clientSocket_sen.send(get.encode('utf-8'))
    print('LSN BP1')
    #print("get sent")
    num = clientSocket_sen.recv(1024)
    test=int(num)
    print("Data Received from LSN:")
    print(test)

 if test>210:
   if status=='on':
      #clientSocket_act.send(off.encode('utf-8'))
      status='off'

 elif test<100:
   if status=='off':
      #clientSocket_act.send(on.encode('utf-8'))
      status='on'

#The above code simply grabs data from a server


#THE CODE BELOW IS WHAT IS CAUSING THE ISSUE

   logvar = logvar+1
   if logvar == 5:
        print("BP2 LSN")
        file.write(time.strftime("%I:%M:%S"))
        file.write("   ")
        file.write(time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))
        file.write("   ")
        file.write("The Lights are: ")
        file.write(status)
        file.write("   ")
        #file.write(volt)
        file.write("\n")
        logvar=0
```

Comment: what do tsn and lsn look like? Also why not just redirect the stdout from each process to a file?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I hope to eventually remove all print's in my final program. In any case, I still don't know how to redirect stdout to a file. Could you tell me how it's done? I want to store the output from both scripts to separate text files.

Comment: I will add a subprocess example. Your problem right now is more than likely not closing your files, try adding `file.close()`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham The program is supposed to run indefinitely, but I'll try adding file.close and see if it logs the data at least once.

Comment: @you are writing to two different files yes?

Comment: I've modified the code such that it opens and closes the file in each iteration. I'm now doing a test run.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham yes

Comment: open with `open('lsn_log.txt', 'a',0)`  for testing so no data will be buffered

Comment: @PadraicCunningham file.close() worked like a charm. Thanks a lot. :D

Comment: No worries, using `with` will do it for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to close your files or let `with` do it for you:

```
with open('lsn_log.txt', 'a') as f:
    while 1:
        time.sleep(0.5)
        clientSocket_sen.send(get.encode('utf-8'))
        print('LSN BP1')
        num = clientSocket_sen.recv(1024)
        test = int(num)
        print("Data Received from LSN:")
        print(test)

        if test > 210:
            if status == 'on':
                #clientSocket_act.send(off.encode('utf-8'))
                status = 'off'

        elif test < 100:
            if status == 'off':
                #clientSocket_act.send(on.encode('utf-8'))
                status = 'on'

        logvar += 1
        if logvar == 5:
            print("BP2 LSN")
            f.write("{} {}  The Lights are:  {}\n".format(time.strftime("%I:%M:%S"), time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"), status))
```